# "Value as" or "value at"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is more correct:

> I value this land-plot **at** exactly $1,000,000

or

> I value this land-plot **as** exactly $1,000,000

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "value at" for an assignment of dollar value - American English speaker here, not sure if this might vary by region.

EDIT to give more context: you can see the different usages of "value...at" and "value...as" by looking at these Google book searches here:

at: https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=vKp4XO2FE4rq_AbN-Ze4Bw&q=%22value+it+at%22&oq=%22value+it+at%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4076.4289.0.4647.3.3.0.0.0.0.119.254.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.69...0.0.tCYWDtL4CLk

as: https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=wap4XKbaIaWb_QbS4K7gAg&q=%22value+it+as%22&oq=%22value+it+as%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...42991.43474.0.43640.4.3.1.0.0.0.153.290.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.153...33i299k1.0.vUiiglwdwTQ

It seems from the search results that "to value as" is a valid expression but is not normally used in reference to monetary amounts. The first example in the "as" results is "...value it as a work of art." This is how I would use "to value as" as well. You value something *as* something else when you judge its worth by comparing it to that something else you know to have a certain value. On the other hand, you value something *at* a specific price.

Comment: This British speaker would also use "at".  But valuation is not an exact science, so the presence of the word "exactly" seems inappropriate - the actual value is the amount someone will pay for it!

Comment: Can you edit to explain more *why* "at" would be suitable for this purpose?